# How to drag and drop 2 different pictures in a form in VB6?

Tags: vb6, drag-and-drop

I am studying how to drag and drop a picture in a form. Now, i can drag and drop a single picture. But, i don't know what will I add to the codes when there are two pictures.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Form_DragDrop(Source As Control, X As Single, Y As Single)
    pic1.Move X, Y
End Sub
```

The name of my 2nd pic is "pic2". Because when I tried this code:

```
Private Sub Form_DragDrop(Source As Control, X As Single, Y As Single)
    pic1.Move X, Y
    pic2.move X, Y
End Sub
```

When I drag and drop either of the two, obviously they will move to the same coordinate. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you are moving two pictures, but it's not clear where your problem is. What is your question? What is what you want your code to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Source** parameter as the control that caused the DragDrop event. The example below will move pic1, or pic2, or any other **PictureBox** control.

```
Private Sub Form_DragDrop(Source As Control, X As Single, Y As Single)

    If TypeOf Source Is PictureBox Then
        Source.Move X, Y
    End If

End Sub
```